# Finding all punctuation in a text file & print count

Tags: sorting, unix, command-line, tr

I have come close to counting all occurrences of punctuation, however punctuation characters that are right next to each other get counted as one.

Like so:

```
cat filename.txt |
tr -sc '[:punct:]' '\n' |
sort |
uniq -c |
sort -bnr`
```

Which prints something like this:

```
15 ,
 9 !
 5 .
 2 ;
 2 !"
 2 '
 1 -
 1 --
 1 :
 1 ?
```

It is clearly only counting punctuation, but how would I separate those that are right next to each other?

Comment: with some file sample content and expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
tr -sc '[:punct:]' '\n'
```

Basically what you do here is replace all the non-punctuation characters with `\n`. So when there is no such character between two punctuation chars , you get them next to each other

You want something like that:

```
cat filename.txt | tr -cd [:punct:] | fold -w 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr
```